# Automatically export JPGs for each level from a multilevel Gimp image

Tags: photoshop, gimp, imagemagick-convert, photoshop-script, xcf

What i say in the title is what i'm doing manually right now for 30 levels!

I'm building different color tshirt previews, every level represents a color and there's a level on top with the draw to be printed.

If I can do it automatically I'll have lot of time saved!

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

Use `convert` from the [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.org) tools:

```
convert multilayer.xcf output.png
```

The result will be a separate PNG for each layer:

```
output-0.png
output-1.png
output-2.png
[…]
```

And: don't use JPG if you continue to print it on T-Shirts… JPG is lossy and doesn't support alpha-channels, which is important for most T-Shirt prints.